# как " разорвать " график в линии?

Tags: qcustomplot

Вот не могу график "разорвать ", почему то первая и последняя точка соединяется , а этого по моей цели не нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
y  0  :  54
y  1  :  55
y  2  :  56
y  3  :  57
y  4  :  58
y  5  :  59
y  6  :  60
y  7  :  61
y  8  :  62
y  9  :  63
y  10  :  64
y  11  :  65
y  12  :  66
y  13  :  67
y  14  :  68
y  15  :  69
y  16  :  70
y  17  :  71
y  18  :  72
y  19  :  73
y  20  :  74
y  21  :  75
y  22  :  76
y  23  :  77
y  24  :  78
y  25  :  79
y  26  :  80
y  27  :  81
y  28  :  82
y  29  :  83
y  30  :  84
y  31  :  85
y  32  :  86
y  33  :  87
y  34  :  88
y  35  :  89
y  36  :  90
y  37  :  91
y  38  :  92
y  39  :  93
y  40  :  94
y  41  :  95
y  42  :  96
y  43  :  97
y  44  :  98
y  45  :  99
y  46  :  100
y  47  :  1
y  48  :  2
y  49  :  3
y  50  :  4
y  51  :  5
y  52  :  6
y  53  :  7
y  54  :  8
y  55  :  9
y  56  :  10
y  57  :  11
y  58  :  12
y  59  :  13
y  60  :  14
y  61  :  15
y  62  :  16
y  63  :  17
y  64  :  18
y  65  :  19
y  66  :  20
y  67  :  21
y  68  :  22
y  69  :  23
y  70  :  24
y  71  :  25
y  72  :  26
y  73  :  27
y  74  :  28
y  75  :  29
y  76  :  30
y  77  :  31
y  78  :  32
y  79  :  33
```

А хочется типа такого

Чтоб  с разрывом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]